# How to Define Function/Procedure in Oracle in User Defined TABLESPACE

Tags: oracle, function, procedure, tablespace

I know that we can create tables in Oracle in user defined TABLESPACE using TABLESPACE keyword, but I can't find anywhere how to define functions/procedures in user defined TABLESPACE.

Can someone help please with details ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Procedures are stored in data dictionary, and it resides in the SYSTEM tablespace.

Comment: Thanks very much Littlefoot for prompt response.